# jQuery specify inner html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a jQuery div element as below;

```
var divEle = $('<div />', {'class': 'editableTxt','data-model-attr':currElmModelAttr,'data-model-id':'currElmModelId'});
```

Now I want to append html text/value inside this div...

So it should render as;

```
<div class="editableTxt" data-model-attr="modelAttr" data-model-id="currElmModelId">My INNER HTML/TEXT</div>
```

I am currently doing;

```
$(this).parent().append(divEle).append($(this).val());
```

But this renders it as separate child element and not inside the divEle...

How do I specify in the same syntax above ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to set html to `divEle`

```
$(this).parent().append(divEle.html($(this).val()));
```

OR

Simply use

```
var divEle = $('<div />', {
    'class': 'editableTxt',
    'data-model-attr': currElmModelAttr,
    'data-model-id': 'currElmModelId',
    'html' : 'My INNER HTML/TEXT'
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y3UKk/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(this).parent().append($(divEle).html($(this).val()));
```

**[Working JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/353/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can try this..

place this after inserting the div..

```
$('.editableTxt').html('my text here');
```